# Python and BeautifulSoup4 - Extract Text from TD tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am stuck after looking through many other questions. My code currently is breaking the data into named rows, but is returning the entire line instead of just the text included, I am just looking for ASCO VALVE MFG., INC. from the following line:  I am not sure how to pull out just that text from the row.

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">****ASCO VALVE MFG., INC.****</font></td>
```

My input looks like:
Headers:

```
 <tr>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_0"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>WH</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_1"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>OrderNo.</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_2"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>Cust.</b></font></td>
        <td align="left" id="ColHead_3"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>Customer Name</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_4"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>Item Number</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_5"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>Item Description 1</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_6"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>Item Description 2</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_7"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>Qty</b></font></td>
        <td align="center" id="ColHead_8"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><b>S/N </b></font></td>
      </tr>
```

Data rows are as below:

```
<tr>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">09</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">92427</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">20668</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">ASCO VALVE MFG., INC.</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">EQPRAN77333</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">RANPAK FILLPAK TT</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">S/N 50742543</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">1</font></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">50742543</font></td>
</tr>
```

My code currently is breaking the data into named rows, but is returning the whole html line.

```
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(output, "html.parser")
find_string = soup1.body.find_all(text="-")
Customer_No = []
Serial_No = []
rows = soup1.find_all("tr")
title = rows[0]
headers = rows[1]
datarows = rows[2:]

for row in datarows :
    if len(row)> 7:
        WHID = row.contents[1]
        ORNO = row.contents[3]
        CSNO = row.contents[5]
        CSNM = row.contents[7]
        ITNO = row.contents[9]
        DESC = row.contents[11]
        DESC2 = row.contents[13]
        QTY = row.contents[15]
        SN = row.contents[17]
        print ITNO
    else:
        continue
```

What I am trying to end up with is a dictionary I guess of [text in CSNO] and [text in SN] pairs to match with a 2nd CSV file.  I hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the text for each element using the `.text` attribute. Something along the following lines should help you get the idea:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">09</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">92427</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">20668</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">ASCO VALVE MFG., INC.</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">EQPRAN77333</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">RANPAK FILLPAK TT</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">S/N 50742543</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">1</font></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><font size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">50742543</font></td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    td_cells = soup.find_all('td')
    for td_cell in td_cells:
        print td_cell.text
```

**Output**

```
09
92427
20668
ASCO VALVE MFG., INC.
EQPRAN77333
RANPAK FILLPAK TT
S/N 50742543
1
50742543
```

To store the text, you could do the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
table_text = []
for row in rows:
    row_text = []
    td_cells = soup.find_all('td')
    for td_cell in td_cells:
        row_text.append(td_cell.text)
    table_text.append(row_text)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how then to assign them to a variable.  Is that something you can give me additional guidance on?

Comment: Thanks so much!  Sorry for the late response,  I tried this approach, but then the data isn't split into the variable appropriate segments.  I will work with it a bit more, but if you have more guidance it is appreciated as always!  Thanks for the help you've already offered.

Comment: No worries. Edit your question to include the table headings row (so I can see what the data/columns) represent, and I can put something together for you

Comment: Maybe also include sample output, so I know exactly what you are after?

Comment: Added what you asked for.  Thanks to much @lambo477  I am excited to be learning, and attacking annoying problems programatically!